# How to pass variables to Reactjs through kubernetes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, kubernetes

I have a simple `reactjs` application and I am going to deploy this in my `kubernetes` cluster.

The `Dockerfile` for the `reactjs` application looks like below:

```
# build env
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine as build
WORKDIR /app
COPY package*.json ./
RUN npm ci
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build

# production env
FROM nginx:stable-alpine
COPY --from=build /app/build /usr/share/nginx/html
EXPOSE 80
CMD ["nginx", "-g", "daemon off;"]
```

And I want to pass two environment variables through `kubernetes` as below:

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: frontend
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: frontend
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: frontend
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: frontend
        image: 19950818/k8s:frontend
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
        - containerPort: 80
        env:
          - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: backend-configs
                key: backend.url                
          - name: REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT
            valueFrom:
              configMapKeyRef:
                name: backend-configs
                key: backend.port
```

I am accessing these variables with the `NodeJs` as below:

```
let url = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL 
let port = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT
```

But How can I modify the `Dockerfile` mentioned above to pass these two variable?

Comment: I am not fluent in the NodeJs ecosystem, but if `process.env...` can directly access system variables, you should be all set.

Comment: @Turing85 don't you think we need to pass this through `Dockerfile` or anything?

Comment: Nope. If We start the container with `docker run ...` , we can use option `-e ...` to set environment variable (for example `docker run -e KEYCLOAK_USER=keycloak -e KEYCLOAK_PASSWORD=keycloak jboss/keycloak`). The same mechanism is used by kubernetes when environment variables are defined.

Comment: The whole idea of microservices is decoupling application from its configuration. Configuration values like environment variables must be passed during runtime. You may specify default values for some variables in your code, but leave possibility to override them using env variables.

Comment: @VasiliAngapov what I have done is half-wrong since I haven't configured/defined default values for those two variables?

Comment: it's totally up to you

Comment: Your front-end (all your javascript) doesn't run in node, docker or kubernetes, it runs in a browser on a user's machine remote from your server with its own distinct environment. There is no direct way to pass those environment variables into your code, other than rewriting your code before it is served -- i.e. writing your code as a template that your build system rewrites with those vars -- or by serving those values via a rest API that you will have to write separately.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The js you have shown:

```js
let url = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_URL 
let port = process.env.REACT_APP_BACKEND_PORT
```

runs in the user's browser, not in kubernetes or docker, therefore the environment variables you set on the server do not exist at the time the code is run. The kubernetes/docker container only serves the javascript as a file to the user's browser.

Basically, you cannot use environment variables in this way.

Comment: This is correct, I guess this is the reason.